# jQuery: add html elements after last option element in a dropdown list

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add some html elements after the last option element of a dropdown list but without success.

This is what I tried:

```
jQuery('select#extended-categories-select-2:last-child').after('<div><b></b></div>');
```

Any other suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Where is your drop down list code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this :

Instead of `last-child`, you need to use `last`.

```
jQuery('select#extended-categories-select-2 option:last').after('<div><b></b></div>');
```

Comment: But then will add it outside of the `select` dropdown and I need it inside the `select` dropdown, after the last `option` element.

Comment: @GrávujMiklósHenrich: a `<select>` can only have `<option>` elements.

Comment: Why do you want to add inside `select` dropdown?

Comment: you can add your custom drop down arrow using css. There is no need to do this.

Comment: @DeadMan yeah but I want the arrow to change direction on dropdown. `jQuery('select#extended-categories-select-2 option:last').after('<div><b></b></div>');` This makes it. Please update your answer so I can accept it. Thanks a lot for the idea! :)

Comment: @DeadMan you forgot the `option`. I will update myself and accept it.

Comment: @GrávujMiklósHenrich which option?

Comment: `jQuery('select#extended-categories-select-2 option:last').after('<div><b></b></div>');`